# PHP - turning register globals off, what is the best way to go about fixing the code?

Tags: php

I am working on a old code base, where programmers assumed that register_globals will always be on.  Hence variables are used without $_GET or $_POST prefix, pretty much in every page (the code base is huge, hundreds of scripts).  I tried turning it off, but the very first script (login script) goes on an infinite loop.

I understand that going through one script at a time, and one line at a time and fixing the variables is probably the only option (adding the prefix $_GET or $_POST as the case may be).  Has anyone does this before?  How did you go about doing it?  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may result in more damage than good but:

1. Grep out the `name="foo"` elements from forms into a CSV or line seperated list something and get the `action` attribute (only if it relates to an actual script)
2. go through the CSV or line-separated list and do a find and replace using sed to replace $currentval with $_POST['currentval']/$_GET['currentval'] or $_REQUEST['currentval'] (but beware cookies)

for example:

```
grep -o -E "(action|name)=\"[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\"" formfile.php | sed -E "s/.*\"([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\"/\\1/" > vars.list
```

Will give you a line separated list of posted variables (ish) which you can loop through in a bash script or something to replace the vars.

**EDIT**

If you want to turn register globals on for one site. Add to your `.htaccess` or Apache config:

`php_value register_globals "On"`

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate `register_globals` using the following code:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $var => $val) $$var = $val;
```

All you then need to do is find a way to have this line run before each script. You can do this in a number of ways:

1. Copy and paste it into the beginning of each file;
2. Using `mod_rewrite` in such a way as to turn each request into (for example) `register_globals.php?forward_to=originally_request_file.php` where `register_globals.php` contains the above line ad then includes the `$_GET['forward_to']` file;
3. There is a directive `auto_prepend_file` in your PHP config which will run a specific script before each file is run as it would be ordinarily. You could have it point to a file with the above line in it. More: http://php.net/auto-prepend-file

Further to point (3), you can set this up in the `.htaccess` file as follows:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/register_globals.php
```

Comment: That's pretty neat idea, though isn't that just like leaving register globals on?? Maybe worse? I wonder if `<input type="hidden" name="$_SESSION['auth']" value="true" />` would do what I think there ;)

Comment: Hm, when I read the question I thought OP was looking for the best way to get the script working again without turning `register_globals` back on in the configutation, as opposed to his priority being that the script worked through directly using `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: this is just equivalent to using the extract() function, right?

Comment: This is just another way of registering every incoming argument as a global variable. It will not solve any of the problems associated with register_globals.

Comment: @Jacco: the problems associated with `register_globals` can easily be overcome. The OP didn't state this was for security reasons. I thought it likely he was wanting to turn off `register_globals` for the sake of other applications running on the web server.

Comment: @icio @Jacco : Could add php_value register_globals "On" to .htaccess in that case.

Comment: Hm, I don't see why not -- though there are some php.ini directives that you can't set in the .htaccess I doubt this would be one.